# Appending a txt file from multiple CSVs in subdirectories

Tags: append, wildcard, batch-processing, subdirectory

I am trying to write a batch file which will append all *.csv files in the immediate subdirectories to a single text file in the current directory.

From various sources I have managed to piece together this code which works fine for files in the current dir but not sub-dirs

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do (type %%a >> csvreport.txt)
```

If anybody could help me with this I would be extremely grateful as I have tried various approaches with wildcards but without success.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option...

```
for /f usebackq %%a in (`dir /s /b *.csv`) do (type %%a >> csvreport.txt)
```

**EDIT:** Reading your details a bit more ... you want just the immediate directories, you can do this:

```
for /f usebackq %%a in (`dir /b /ad`) do for %%b in ("%%a"\*.csv) do (type "%%b" >> csvreport.txt)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am nesting  this batch file in a VB script, so all of this is very useful.

cheers

Comment: I tried the command as suggested with `%%a` and got errors.  Turns out that in Windows 7, you don't use variables as `%%a`, it needs to be prefixed with a single `%` (so `%a`).

Comment: Actually the double percent sign is needed when the command is in a .bat file. If you're just running this on the command prompt then you only need a single percent sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /R .\ %%a in (*.csv) do (type %%a >> csvreport.txt)
```

The /R indicates **recursive** and the parameter afterward is the folder in which to start (.\ is the current directory).

You can find up more if you run `for /?`

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /ad /b > dirs.txt
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (dirs.txt) do cd %%i & for %%b in (*.csv) do (type %%b >> c:\csvreport.txt) & cd ..
```

Using the /R flag will traverse all subdirectory trees. You can nest the 'for' statements to only work with the immediate subdirectories but not their subdirectories.